# "Boot partition full" warnings

Tags: 16.04, package-management, kernel

I am new to Linux. I am getting warning message every time saying my boot partition is having low memory. Following are the contents of my `/boot`.

```
ls /boot/
abi-4.10.0-28-generic         initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
abi-4.10.0-40-generic         lost+found
abi-4.10.0-42-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.13.0-26-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.13.0-32-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-4.13.0-36-generic         retpoline-4.13.0-36-generic
abi-4.13.0-37-generic         retpoline-4.13.0-37-generic
config-4.10.0-28-generic      System.map-4.10.0-28-generic
config-4.10.0-40-generic      System.map-4.10.0-40-generic
config-4.10.0-42-generic      System.map-4.10.0-42-generic
config-4.13.0-26-generic      System.map-4.13.0-26-generic
config-4.13.0-32-generic      System.map-4.13.0-32-generic
config-4.13.0-36-generic      System.map-4.13.0-36-generic
config-4.13.0-37-generic      System.map-4.13.0-37-generic
efi                           vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-4.10.0-40-generic
initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic  vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
initrd.img-4.10.0-40-generic  vmlinuz-4.13.0-26-generic
initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic  vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
initrd.img-4.13.0-26-generic  vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic  vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
```

Please advise how can I clean my `/boot` partition as I have no idea what these files do.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is the actual message? Removing old kernels might help as per - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: The message is boot partition is almost full only 22 MB is left

Comment: I followed the link and did manual removal of kernel but getting the following error
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

At the command line run:

```
df -h | grep boot
```

This will show you how much space is free on your /boot partition. In my case it looks pretty bad.

```
/dev/sdb1                    472M  460M     0 100% /boot
```

As already mentioned, you can [clean up old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) and packages to help free up some space.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

The operation can take quite a while as it looks for old kernels and other packages which can be removed.

Then run **df -h | grep boot** again to check your space on /boot

```
/dev/sdb1                    472M  143M  306M  32% /boot
```

Much better!